# Which tools for differential expression analysis in scRNA-Seq?

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq, differential-expression

I am starting to run analysis for differential expression in scRNA-Seq. Which tools are available for this kind of analysis?

Can tools for bulk RNA-Seq like [DESeq](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq/inst/doc/DESeq.pdf) be used for scRNA-Seq?

Comment: I recommend this [page](https://www.scrna-tools.org) to learn about other tools

Comment: @Llopis thanks. I'd recommend also this curated repository for Single-Cell analysis: https://github.com/seandavi/awesome-single-cell

Comment: Yes, and there's also the [online course](https://hemberg-lab.github.io/scRNA.seq.course/introduction-to-single-cell-rna-seq.html), where it says that "Several computational analysis methods from bulk RNA-seq can be used"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Jaakkola et al. (ref. 1):

> Based on our comparisons, DESeq and Limma without any modifications are not suitable for scRNA-seq data analysis, and yet, they have performed well in the context of bulk RNA-seq data.

They also provided a summary of the comparison between 5 tools (2 designed for Single-Cell, 2 designed for bulk, 1 general):

[image: compar]

In my case I ended up using MAST (ref. 2, [github](https://github.com/RGLab/MAST)).

1. Jaakkola, M. K., Seyednasrollah, F., Mehmood, A. & Elo, L. L. [Comparison of methods to detect differentially expressed genes between single-cell populations.](https://academic.oup.com/bib/article/18/5/735/2562772) Briefings in Bioinformatics 18, 735–743 (2017).
2. Finak, G. et al. [MAST: A flexible statistical framework for assessing transcriptional changes and characterizing heterogeneity in single-cell RNA sequencing data.](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-015-0844-5) Genome Biol. 16, 1183 (2015).

Comment: In a paper of Soneson & Robinson (2018) in Nature Methods ([doi:10.1038/nmeth.4612](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.4612)), the authors concluded that "bulk" methods do not perform worse than methods developed specifically for scRNA-seq.

Comment: @b.nota Thank you! Can you edit my question to reflect also your comment?